# Поиск пропущеных значений при переборе массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Есть массив с объектами (deliveryCost - страна и стоимость доставки в страну). Необходимо реализовать вызов функции с запрашиваемой страной: если она (country) есть в массиве - отобразить стоимость доставки (cost). Если её нет, просто отобразить в консоли: "В вашу страну доставка не осуществляется".

Я пробовал через перебор массива (map, filter, find..) - в моей реализации, когда страна не найдена, все равно перебирается весь массив и выводится сообщение столько раз, сколько объектов в массиве. Значит, неверна сама реализация.

Подскажите, где я допускаю ошибку.
Спасибо Вам!

```js
const deliveryCost = [
  { country: "Китай", cost: 100 },
  { country: "Чили", cost: 250 },
  { country: "Австралия", cost: 170 },
  { country: "Индия", cost: 80 },
  { country: "Ямайка", cost: 120 }
];

const countryForDelivery = (arr, countryName) => {
  arr.map(elem => {
    if (elem.country === countryName) {
      yesDelivery(elem.country, elem.cost);
    } else {
      noDelivery(countryName);
    }
  });
};

function yesDelivery(country, cost) {
  console.log(`Доставка в ${country} будет стоить ${cost} кредитов`);
}

function noDelivery(country) {
  console.log(`В ${country} доставка не доступна`);
}

countryForDelivery(deliveryCost, "Индия"); // есть в списке
countryForDelivery(deliveryCost, "Исландия"); // нет в списке
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам `map` в данном случае не нужен, т.к. он предназначен для создания нового массива на основании существующего (т.е. для каждого элемента вызывается ваша функция, поэтому в консоли и куча сообщений). Вам достаточно с помощью `filter`/`find` найти нужный элемент и если он есть выводить одно сообщение, если нет - другое.

```
const countryForDelivery = (arr, countryName) => {
    const elem = arr.find(elem => elem.country === countryName);
    if (elem) {
        yesDelivery(elem.country, elem.cost);
    } else {
        noDelivery(countryName);
    }
};
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я понял свою ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Обычно, имеет смысл создать производный `Map` (или обычный объект) для скоростного доступа по одному из полей, *без какого-либо перебора вложенных объектов*.
Почему это лучше - потому что объекты это хэш-таблицы. При доступе по ключам, интерпретатор использует только их хэши (а это значительно быстрее, чем любой перебор в юзеркоде, будь то `for`+`if` или `find`).

---

**Объект Map, и внешняя функция** (внутренний поиск чуть быстрее):

```js
const deliveryCostData = [
  { country: "Китай", cost: 100 },
  { country: "Чили", cost: 250 },
  { country: "Австралия", cost: 170 },
  { country: "Индия", cost: 80 },
  { country: "Ямайка", cost: 120 }
];
const deliveryCostMap = deliveryCostData.reduce(
  (rslt, obj) => rslt.set(obj.country, obj) 
, new Map); 

const deliveryFor = country => {
  const entry = deliveryCostMap.get(country); 
  if (!entry || (typeof entry.cost === 'undefined'))
    console.log(`В ${country} доставка не доступна`);
  else
    console.log(`Доставка в ${country} будет стоить ${entry.cost} кредитов`);
}; 

deliveryFor('Индия'); // есть в списке
deliveryFor('Исландия'); // нет в списке
```

**Обычный объект, с методом** (удобнее благодаря инкапсуляции):

```js
const deliveryCostData = [
  { country: "Китай", cost: 100 },
  { country: "Чили", cost: 250 },
  { country: "Австралия", cost: 170 },
  { country: "Индия", cost: 80 },
  { country: "Ямайка", cost: 120 }
];
const delivery = deliveryCostData.reduce(
  (rslt, obj) => Object.assign(rslt, { [obj.country]: obj }) 
, {
    forCountry(country) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(country))
        console.log(`Доставка в ${country} будет стоить ${this[country].cost} кредитов`); 
      else
        console.log(`В ${country} доставка не доступна`);
    }, 
  }
); 

delivery.forCountry('Индия'); // есть в списке
delivery.forCountry('Исландия'); // нет в списке
```

В обоих случаях имеет смысл присваивать в качестве значения *весь объект*, а не только его поле `cost`. Потому что:

- Эффективно по ресурсам (**1.** объекты присваиваются по ссылке, доп. память не выделяется; **2.** интерпретатору не нужно запоминать дублирующую схему объектов, и выполнять сопутствующие проверки схем на каждой итерации построения словаря)
- Как следствие передачи по ссылке, получаем взаимосвязь данных в объектах и возможность упрощения логики (изменение `cost` или добавление новых свойств в объекты `deliveryCostData`, автоматически отразится на объектах в словаре - при таких операциях,  нет нужды его перестраивать)
- Значительно упрощается поддержка кода (если в будущем добавятся еще "постоянные" поля помимо `cost`, код не нужно будет переписывать - достаточно будет дополнить его новыми хелперами/методами).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ и возможные решения! Второй вариант особенно нравится - код чище и производительнее

Comment: @Mr.Pickles, Производительнее (в большинстве случаев) будет первый вариант, на `Map` - поэтому я и написал два варианта, каждый имеет свои плюсы и минусы "наследуемые" от объекта-словаря.

Comment: В таких задачах, учитывать стоит только производительность чтения (получение объекта по ключу), как более частой операции - а насколько быстро строится/редактируется словарь, не так важно.

Comment: Буду на это обращать внимание, спасибо Вам!